# How to modify xml node with mixed content

Tags: c#, xml

I have modify "duyurular.xml", but node `<baslik>` non-standard and contains value. 
How to change node `<baslik>` value.

"duyurular.xml" file structure:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <duyurular>
      <duyuru>
        <baslik>Okul Müdürlüğü<kurum>Eğitim-Öğretim</kurum><tarih>11.11.2011-17:17</tarih><url>http://www.example.com/XmlDuyuru.aspx?duyurudetayId=2012581131705</url><duyurudetay>Detay bilgileri One</duyurudetay><id>2012581131705</id></baslik>
        <baslik>AB Eğitim ve Gençlik <kurum>ARGE</kurum><tarih>11.11.2011-17:17</tarih><url>http://www.example.com/XmlDuyuru.aspx?duyurudetayId=2012581131701</url><duyurudetay>Detay bilgileri Two</duyurudetay><id>2012581131701</id></baslik>
      </duyuru>
    </duyurular>
```

C# Code behind:

```
    void xmDuzelt(string idim)
    {
        string dosyaadi = Server.MapPath("~/xml/") + "duyurular.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(dosyaadi);

        var q = from duzey1 in doc.Descendants("duyuru")
                let elemnt = duzey1.Element("baslik").Element("id")                    
                where elemnt != null && elemnt.Value == idim
                select duzey1;

        foreach (var item in q)
                {
                    item.Element("baslik").Element("kurum").Value = this.txtKurum.Text;
                    item.Element("baslik").Element("duyurudetay").Value = this.txtduyurudetay.Value;                    
                }       
        doc.Save(dosyaadi);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I hope the modified title describes your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Elements and attributes modified as usual.

Baslik element's text modified by next ways:

if text count in baslik element is one always:

```
    var baslik = item.Element("baslik");

    var text = baslik.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First();
    text.Value = new_baslik_text;
```

if zero or one:

```
    var text = baslik.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (text != null)
      text.Value = new_baslik_text;
    else
      baslik.AddFirst(new XText(new_baslik_text));
```

if zero or many:

```
    foreach (var text in baslik.Nodes().OfType<XText>().ToArray())
      text.Remove();
    baslik.AddFirst(new XText(new_baslik_text));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the children elements, you can do it like this:

```
var baslik = item.Element("baslik");
var children = baslik.Elements().ToArray();
baslik.Value = "new value"; // removes any children
foreach (XElement child in children) // re-add child elements
    baslik.Add(child);
```